# Efficient Minkowski sum calculation

Tags: java, algorithm, set

I wonder whether there is an algorithm to efficiently calculate
a *discrete 1-dimensional* Minkowski sum. The Minkowski sum is defined as:

```
S + T = { x + y | x in S, y in T }
```

Could it be that we can represent the sets as lists, sort S and T, and 
then do something similarly to computing the union of two sets. i.e. walk 
along the sets in parallel and generate the result.

Are there such algorithms known where I don't have to additionally sort the
result to remove overlapping cases x1+y1 = x2+y2? Preferably formulated in Java?

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if there were an algorithm significantly better than quadratic-time.

Comment: I found this in one of the docs in repos on my college. Maybe that will help: http://iwi138.iwinet.rug.nl/informatica/users/bekker/publications/bekker001.PS

Comment: @Lopina that's a dead link. j4n bur53 why you didn't accept the answer, are you still waiting?

Comment: @gsamaras See my comment in the answer from user1071136, I am still waiting for an improved version. But feel free to vote it up anyway. I have already spent all my votes.

Comment: I already upvoted you and him @j4nbur53, pretty sure you won't get an improved version. :)

Comment: I wrote everything about Minkowski Sums in my blog with some examples. Check this out: https://minkowski-sum.herokuapp.com/minkownski-sum.html

Comment: @ Joan Gerard you should post an answer here, and not only a comment.

Answer (score 5):

First, the size of the output can be `O(nm)`, if there are no collisions (e.g., `A={0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}`, `B={n, 2*n, 3*n, ...n*n}`), so if we depend on `n` and `m`, we have no hope of finding a sub-quadratic algorithm. 
A straightforward one is computing all pairs (`O(nm)`), sorting and unique-ing (total of `O(nm log nm)`.

If you have an upper bound `M` such that `x <= M` for all `x` in `A union B`, we can compute the sum in `O(M log M)` in the following way.

1. Generate the characteristic vectors `A[i] = 1 ff i \in A, 0 otherwise` and similarly for `B`. Each such vector is of size `M`.
2. Compute the convolution of `A` and `B` using FFT (time: `O(M log M)`). Output size is O(`M`).
3. Scan output `O` - at each cell, `O[i]` is nonzero iff `i` is an element of the Minkowski sum.

Proof: `O[i] != 0` iff there exists `k` such that `A[k] != 0` and `B[i-k] != 0`, iff `k \in A` and `i-k \in B`, iff `k + i-k`, that is `i`, is in the Minkowski sum.

(Taken from [this paper](http://www.cs.utep.edu/vladik/misha5.pdf))

Comment: If 0 =< y,x =< M, then 0=< x+y =< 2*M. But the convolution is only of size M, probably from the limmited image application area in the paper, so I guess we would need a little adaptation. But otherwise quite fascinating lead.

Answer (score 0):

Sort S and T, iterate over S searching for matching elements in T, each time you find a match remove the element from S and T and put it in a new set U. Because they are sorted, once you find a match in T, further comparisons in T can start from the last match.

Now S, T and U are all disjoint. So iterate over S and T adding each one, and S and U, and T and U. Finally iterate over U, and add every element in U by every element in U whose set index is equal to or greater than the current set index.

Sadly the algorithm is still O(n^2) with this optimization. If T and S are identical it will be 2x faster than the naive solution. You also don't have to search in the output set for duplicates.

Comment: Uh right. I meant add. When I typed it I was thinking about set multiplication - where you combine all elements in a set.

Comment: Well yes and no. I guess it depends on the properties of addition of the elements. If it is possible that there are multiple ways to get the same result then it won't work - you still have to  search the output set. If there is only one way to get any result then it would be a little faster then iterating over both sets. You don't really have N here. You have N and M, the sizes of T and S. So its really O( M*N + log2N + log2M ). If you do the search after combination then it would be O(M*N + log2(M*N))

Comment: Logarithm multiplication law, log(m*n) = log m + log n. So there is no difference. I was hoping something can be done by iterating in parallel over S and T. For example a corresponding union algorithm is complexity O(n+m).